# Consulta de base de datos con insquery falla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código, pero al realizar el proceso de inserción en el formulario simplemente no agrega nada a la base de datos.

```
<?php
      require 'database.php';
      $BD = new DB();
      $BD->connect();
      mysqli_set_charset($BD->connect,"utf8");

      $idventa=$_POST['idventa'];
      $idticket=$_POST['idticket'];
      $datein=$_POST['datein'];
      $price=$_POST['price'];
      $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
      $product=$_POST['product'];

      if(empty($_POST['idventa'])){
        header("Location: ventas.php");
      }else{
        $BD->insquery("INSERT INTO ventas (idventa,idticket,fingreso,precio,cantidad,producto) VALUES ('$idventa','$idticket','$datein','$price',
          '$quantity','$product'");
          header("Location: ventas.php");
      }
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ¿ya has depurado las variables que recibes? (`var_dump($_POST['tuValor']);`) ¿Has probado que el método `insquery()` haga algo (hardcode de datos)? Y por último, ¿has oído hablar de una vulnerabilidad llamada [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL)? Saludos

Comment: estoy casi seguro que tu error es debido a que estás insertando `idventa ` como `'$idVentas'`, cuando probablemente inventa sea un `int`, es decir tu estás pasando el valor como si fuera un `varchar`, para comprobar, pon la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Buenas, he buscado información sobre el método insquery() que estás usando y por ahora he encontrado esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: idventa en tu base de datos es una primary key ?